# ACL on Docker overlay network

Tags: networking, docker, acl

I have a relatively large Docker swarm with several dozen micro-web-services running on it.

As only two or three of these services need external access, most of the inter-container/service communication happens over a single overlay network.

In the interests of tightening platform security I would like to impose some service-name based access control on the overlay network to prevent container 'cross-talk'.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of doing this, and creating a new overlay network for every service link seems a little bit unmanageable?

What I hope to accomplish is:

```
$ docker network create myoverlay -d overlay
$ docker service create --name web1 --net myoverlay apache
$ docker service create --name web2 --net myoverlay nginx
$ docker service create --name database1 --net myoverlay mysql
$ docker service create --name database2 --net myoverlay cassandra

web1 -> database1 //allowed
web2 -> database2 //allowed

web1 -> database2 //denied
web2 -> database1 //denied
```

Comment: This is precisely the use case for multiple docker networks. Why do you feel that multiple networks are unmanageable where maintaining ACL's wouldn't be?

Comment: Because of the requirement for inhouse naming conventions and more careful allocation of IPs to avoid the 'out of box' conflict with our AWS  ranges.  Cataloging exponentially growing list things is harder than a classical single iptables/ufw script...

Comment: I agree with @BMitch-- using another network is the correct approach here.